# beginner - obtain the top 3 in sql (taking same total score into account)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi I am trying to obtain the top 3 ranking and pass them to php, and if total score of two ID's are the same, both have the same rank. I tried to use `limit 0, 3` and `rank()` but only get the the first 3 records without taking same total score into account.

```
╔════╦════════════╗
║ ID ║ TOTALSCORE ║
╠════╬════════════╣
║  7 ║         20 ║
║  4 ║         20 ║
║  6 ║         18 ║
║  9 ║         18 ║
║  1 ║         16 ║
╚════╩════════════╝
```

Then, the ranking should be

```
╔══════╦════╗
║ RANK ║ ID ║
╠══════╬════╣
║    1 ║  7 ║
║    1 ║  4 ║
║    2 ║  6 ║
║    2 ║  9 ║
║    3 ║  1 ║
╚══════╩════╝
```

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: Sorry I dont get it, what is the problem with my question? I searched online but couldnt find any answer to it.

Comment: @JohnConde based on the OPs description and mentioning 'limit' and 'rank()' she has achieved to get a top 3, just not one with the *same score* taken into account. This looks like a perfectly valid question to me. In this case, OPs full SQL queries are not really required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `MySQL` do not support `Window Function` like any RDBMS has, you can still simulate what `DENSE_RANK()` can do by using *user define variables*, eg

```
SELECT  a.ID, a.TotalScore, b.Rank
FROM    TableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  TotalScore, @rn := @rn + 1 Rank
            FROM
                    (
                        SELECT  DISTINCT TotalScore
                        FROM    TableName
                    ) a, (SELECT @rn := 0) b
            ORDER   BY TotalScore DESC
        ) b ON  a.TotalScore = b.TotalScore
WHERE   Rank <= 3
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76e2e2/5)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*Another Example*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3eaeb/2)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦════════════╦══════╗
║ ID ║ TOTALSCORE ║ RANK ║
╠════╬════════════╬══════╣
║  7 ║         20 ║    1 ║
║  4 ║         20 ║    1 ║
║  6 ║         18 ║    2 ║
║  9 ║         18 ║    2 ║
║  1 ║         16 ║    3 ║
╚════╩════════════╩══════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.id, t.totalscore,
       (select count(distinct t2.totalscore) from t2 where t2.totalscore >= t.totalscore
       ) as rank
from t
```

One advantage is that this is standard SQL that should run on any database.